# sitemap - following mvcsitemapprovider but categorization is confusing me

Tags: sitemap, asp.net-mvc

I'm using mvcsitemapprovider for sitemap. http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

```
 public class StoreDetailsDynamicNodeProvider 
        : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
    { 
        MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

        public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection() 
        { 
            // Build value 
            var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();

            // Create a node for each album 
            foreach (var album in storeDB.Albums.Include("Genre")) 
            { 
                DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode(); 
                node.Title = album.Title; 
                node.ParentKey = "Genre_" + album.Genre.Name; 
                node.RouteValues.Add("id", album.AlbumId);

                returnValue.Add(node); 
            }

            // Return 
            return returnValue; 
        } 
    }
```

this is the code on their website for registering dynamic website nodes. How do I modify this to adapt to my website's categorization is confusing me.

Here is the layout of my website:

```
home->approved->
                education             entertainment               business
                    |                      |                        |
            kid, teenager, adult   kid, teenager, adult     kid, teenager, adult
                    |                      |                        |
                  and so on..            and so on..              and so on..

home->not approved->
                education             entertainment               business
                    |                      |                        |
            kid, teenager, adult   kid, teenager, adult     kid, teenager, adult
                    |                      |                        |
                  and so on..            and so on..              and so on..
```

and only after going through so many levels, the entries come up.

what's confusing me is as you can see entries in my sitemap do not have one unique parent key. Even in the database, the way things are stored as is that each row of an entry in the database would know that it belongs to approved, entertainment, kid, etc... like below:

```
Entry1 | approved | education | kid | levelx | levely | levelz ...
```

how would one organize sitemap of something like that for sitemap?

**Edit: I posted a similar question on stackoverflow, but I felt this may be more appropriate place.**

Comment: Programming questions definitely belong at StackOverflow. I'll just close this one since you also posted it over there.

Comment: @John Conde, this question was more supposed to address how to organize my sitemap.

Comment: How to organize it from a programming point of view. That's the domain of SO. If it were how to organize it for usability, SEO, etc, it would belong here.